# What's going on in this type signature? (Vector.Mutable modifiers in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-signature, io-monad, st-monad

Mutable vectors in Haskell have three element-level mutators:

```
read :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m a
write :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> a -> m ()
swap :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> Int -> m ()
```

Now I can use these fine --

```
import Data.Vector
import Data.Vector.Mutable 
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive 

incrAt :: Vector Double -> Int -> Vector Double
incrAt vec i = runST $ do
  mvec <- thaw vec
  oldval <- read mvec i
  write mvec i (oldval + 1)
  freeze mvec
```

But what is going on here?  What is a `PrimMonad`?  And is `PrimState` a constructor?

I understand there is some binding going on here, on a `PrimMonad` class monad. `thaw` returns `m (MVector (PrimState m) a)`, where `m` is a `PrimMonad`... but the monad contains itself?  Why is `m` inside the context of another `m`?

I see that everything is basically binding on this `PrimState` or `PrimMonad`, but I don't see how this has to do with mutable/storable vectors.  Is there something special about those typeclasses that allow them to store state?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are using the [vector package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Mutable.html), as in

```
import Data.Vector.Mutable
```

Following the `PrimMonad` type class leads to low level details; the thing to notice is the two instances:

```
instance PrimMonad IO where ...
instance PrimMonad (ST s) where ...
```

So `(PrimMonad m)` is just a way of saying `m` is either `IO` or `(ST s)`.  These are the two basic monads in which Haskell is setup to let you mutate memory.  To be clear, `m` is a type constructor and applying `m` to a type like `Int` gives a type: `m Int`.

To emphasize: `IO` and `(ST s)` are special because they allow you to "store state" using this ability to mutate the actual memory.  They expose this capability in a raw form that the rest of Haskell hides.

Now PrimState is a newish thing: an [associated data type](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#assoc-decl).  In the `PrimMonad` type class there is a declaration:

```
-- | Class of primitive state-transformer monads
class Monad m => PrimMonad m where
  -- | State token type
  type PrimState m
```

The type that `(PrimState m)` will be in your code depends on what the instance for `(PrimMonad m)` assigned to it.

```
instance PrimMonad IO where
  type PrimState IO = RealWorld

instance PrimMonad (ST s) where
  type PrimState (ST s) = s
```

The `RealWorld` type is an low level internal implementation detail of IO in GHC.  The `s` type attached to `(ST s)` is the existential type trick that lets `runST` prove that nothing mutable has escaped the `(ST s)` monad.

To make the same code work in `IO` and `(ST s)` the `PrimMonad` type-class (with associated `PrimState`) are used to provide ad-hoc overloading.

Comment: is there any way I can play with defining types so that the call signature gets a little cleaner?  for example if I know I'm always going to be using it in the context of `ST`

Comment: You then replace 'm' with (ST s) and drop the 'PrimMonad m =>' prefix.

Comment: You then replace (PrimState (ST s)) with 's'.

Comment: You can then then use 'type MV s a = MVector s a'

Comment: Note that technically, this is an "associated *type* (synonym) (family)", not an "associated *data* type (family)".  The difference is that an associated data type creates a brand new type, and would look like `data PrimState (ST s) = STPrimState s`, which would of course be entirely unhelpful in this circumstance :-)